# ListView with custom ListCell

Tags: javafx, scalafx

I am learning scalaFX/JavaFX so as a warm up, and part of a larger project, I'm writing a remote file chooser. Binding a `ListView` to an `ObservableBuffer[File]`. But I don't want `File.toString` as text, so instead of extending `File` I wanted to use `ListCell`. I didn't find any examples that did that so I figured I'd post this.

This was alright but I was getting `Null` files, then when skipping the `Null`s I still had the old files in the list (if there are x files before the change and x- after, you have cells with old data).

In the end I put `""` for null files and the missing file items are removed from the `ListView`. I don't see any mention of this in the `ListView` API.

Does this seem right to you? It seems to me that there should be another place to remove the cells. The default `cellFactory` handled this well.

```
val fileList = new ListView[File](fileSystemModel.fileList) {
      cellFactory = { _ =>
        new ListCell[File] {
          item.onChange {
            (_, _, file) =>
              if (file != null) {
                text = s"${file.getName}${if (file.isDirectory) "/" else ""}"
              } else text = ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know ScalaFX at all, but your code looks weird.  Normally when you subclass cell you override [updateItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem-T-boolean-) and you follow a code pattern as outlined in the linked Cell Javadoc (invoke super.updateItem and include logic for handling empty or null cells during the update), failure to do so correctly usually results in behavior such as you mention: "still had the old files in the list".

Comment: Sometimes it is more clear just to use Java.  I am writing JavaFX from Scala and sometimes it takes a while to get from how it would be done in Java to how it is done in Scala.   Only once so far have I had to extend a class in Java though, you can almost always us a function.

Answer (score 0):

It was extremely weird, but I did it:

```
import javafx.scene.{control => jfxsc}

case class Item(name: String)

items = ... //ListView[Item]

items.cellFactory = (lv: ListView[Item]) => {
    new ListCell(new jfxsc.ListCell[Item] {
    override def updateItem(item: Item, empty: Boolean): Unit = {
        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null)
            setGraphic(null)
        } else {
            setText(item.name)
        }
    }
    })
}
```

Comment: In the end I gave up on scalaFX.  These things that should be little details turn out to be big problems, other things that are more work in FX it makes easy.  It's just not that much more verbose to write FX in Scala.  I did like the way scalaFX organizes the code into a much more Scala like pattern.  FX forces you to use the same sort of verbose, procedural configuration of elements that Swing did.